# Ngrx/effect and angular 2 interceptor should we use both?

Tags: angular, interceptor, ngrx-effects

I'm still trying to find my way with the redux pattern. it appears to me that ngrx/effect can pretty much to the same thing angular interceptor do. I wrote some intereptor to add hawk credentials in all request should i move this to ngrx/effect? or should i use both?

Answer (score 0):

actually ngrx/effect and interceptor both are not same.
ngrx/effect handle side effect of a ngrx/store action 
sometimes when you need service call or any other job to complete a action then you should use @effect for asynchronous events in ngrx store.
its totally work out of normal dispatch->action->reducer->state  pattern .
   and after doing your job in @effect you can dispatch(trigger) another action.